# Auto compressing sencha touch files for delivery onto Heroku

Tags: model-view-controller, optimization, compression, heroku, sencha-touch

I have a sencha touch app built using MVC and deployed onto Heroku.

Heroku is awesome becuase it makes delivery to the cloud seamless from my local environment.

HOWEVER, IDEALLY, I'd like the process of transferring to Heroku compress my files into one cs and one js. This way i can continue developing locally using uncompressed files and updating the app compresses and deploys the optimized version.

As of now my data size is 1.0MB and takes 3 seconds. Too much! (of course I am using debug versions of sencha at the moment.)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we use [asset_packager](https://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager) - basically a yml file which lists all your js and css files and then before deployment there's a rake rask which produces a single js and css file which we when then deploy to Heroku

Comment: This is a good solution. Thanks. I also found Jammit which works really well for me: http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/